# Looping div from parent div using JQuery

Tags: jquery

guys..

I just wanna loop my div from return json result....as you can see here's the desire result I'm after

```
<div id="doaimgbox"><!-- parent div -->

  <!-- start looping portion -->
  <!-- I wanna loop this div based on length json return result let's say 3 -->

    <div class="imgdiv">

        <img src="imagedoa/d0.jpg" width="400" height="150" />
        <div id="rbox">
            Was sent <span class="counter"></span> times.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span class="buttonshare"><a href="">Click to select</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- looping portion -->
```

as you can see below here are my attempt but no to avail..

```
$.ajax({type :'GET',
    url : 'getallimg.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        $("#loader").hide(500);
        $("<div class='imgdiv'><img src='imagedoa/"+item.imgname+".jpg' width='450' height='150' /></div></br>")
        .appendTo("#doaimgbox");
       });
```

Really need help ..suggest me the best solution or suggestion..tq

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. You might try putting "console.log(data);" into your success function, to see if your data is coming back the way it should. If you don't see any results, it means bad JSON from the server, in which case visit the URL by hand to see what you get.